# Notifications (RSS or mailing list) of CVE with high scores for Windows and Red Hat?

Tags: windows, linux, cve

I'm looking for a RSS feed or a mailing list that would allow me to be alerted of new CVEs impacting Windows or Red Hat that have a very high score, such as the recent ones for Shellshock and Winshock for example. Basically, a simple way to be proactive about updates that require immediate action and can't wait until the next month's patch cycle.

Is there such a list or is it just wishful thinking?

So far I found the NVD's 8-days analyzed CVEs RSS feed (https://nvd.nist.gov/download/nvd-rss-analyzed.xml), but you don't see the score in the subject, so it's hard to filter (i.e. if I wanted to alert whenever I see score > 8 for example).

Red Hat and Microsoft both have some form of mailing lists or RSS feeds, but none show the actual CVE score, and you need to open the related CVE separately and read the details. It's a bit time consuming to open each notification one by one to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CVE Details allows you to create a customized RSS feed with certain CVSS scores.  : http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-feeds-form.php

However, I'm not sure if there's a way to filter out only Windows & Red Hat OS vulns.. but perhaps someone has an idea?

Comment: Ahhhh! Goodies :) That's at least a good start, thanks.

Comment: Found how, you can use the product_id and vendor_id fields in the GET query to narrow the search. This is perfect ! Accepted as the answer.